# recuresion, recursion, and one more time recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

What is difference here:

## 1:

```
int function(int n==0){
if(n ==4) return function( ++n);
else return function(n--)

return 2;
}
```

## 2

```
int function(int n==0){
if(n ==4)  function( ++n);
else function(n--)

return 2;
}
```

And second question:

```
int function( int m){
if( m ==2) return function( m+2) + function(m+3);

return 2;
}
```

I don't understand how behave this function at whole. More or less I understand one calling- I mean:

```
if( m ==2) return function( m+2);
```

but it:

```
if( m ==2) return function( m+2) + function(m+3);
```

isn't understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> What is difference here:

Not much difference: they both don't compile for the same reasons.

> I don't understand how behave this function at whole.

It will call either `function( m+2)` or `function( m+3)` first, and then finish its recursion, and then move to the other (`function( m+3)` or `function( m+2)` respectively) and sum the returned values of both. Recursively.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any great difference between the first and the second functions, The both will not be compiled because this construction of the list of parameters

```
int function(int n==0){
```

is invalid. I think there should be the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator

```
int function(int n = 0){
```

Nevertheless the both functions have an infinite recursion. So the presence or the absence of the return statements is not important.

As for the last function then there all is simple

```
int function( int m){
if( m ==2) return function( m+2) + function(m+3);

return 2;
}
```

If m is not equal to 2 then the function returns 2. Otherwise it calls itself with an argument that is not equal to 2. So each called function will return 2. 2 + 2 will be equal to 4. 
So the function returns either 2 when its argument is not equal to 2 or 4 otherwise.